# Making a CSS Loop Typing Effect Responsive

Tags: html, css, animation, responsive, caret

I've created a typewriter effect using HTML and CSS. It works fine on the web, but on mobile it doesn't fit into the width of the screen. How do I make the effect responsive? I'd like the background image to remain static. Here's my code:

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: typing 5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 15em
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Model Running . . .</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desktop

[image: Desktop rendering]

Mobile

[image: Mobile rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `@media` to reduce the `font-size` on the mobile version. That means, If the screen is not wider than 800px then reduce the `font-size`. If it's not what you want then let me know.

Here is the code:

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: typing 5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 15em
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .typewriter h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: typing 5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  @keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
    to {
      width: 15em
    }
  }

  @keyframes blink-caret {
    from,
    to {
      border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
      border-color: orange;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Model Running . . .</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the image I you can add max-width (100%/100vw)
But for the text I think you have to use [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) to set different sizes.